# Google Photos on Windows 10 Screensaver

Tags: windows-10, photos, screensaver, google-photos

I'm trying to set up an automated screensaver for my parents on their Windows 10 machine. Idea being a few minutes of idle time then shows random pictures from Google Photos. Right now Windows has a very limited photo screensaver built-in, but of course it doesn't reach into Google Photos where most of their pictures live.

A bunch of searches doesn't pull up any recent advice on how to do this. I've tried installing the Google Drive windows client but there's no obvious place to look for Google Photos.

I'd even think about setting up a live usb stick running Linux in extremis.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could simply leave the *Google Photos* app running: https://support.google.com/photos/thread/753141/how-do-i-view-all-photos-screenshots-camera-etc-in-one-photostream?hl=en . Put a shortcut to it on the desktop. It would **not** be a good idea to leave it running in the background when the machine is not in use, though, continually using network and system resources.

Comment: Where is a Google Photos app for Windows?

Comment: Slightly unrelated: I'd recommend the Bing Wallpaper app for Windows, so that the desktop background is updated each day with the Bing Wallpaper.